# find object if attribute not exists and add that attribute with value

Tags: javascript

I have array of objects like below:

```
checklist= [
    {
      "participantId": 13,
      "rankStatus": "participated",
      "rank": 3,
      "comment": "my comment",
      "horse_name": "test232 fdfgdg",
      "country": "Afghanistan",
      "life_number": null
    },
    {
      "participantId": 12,
      "rankStatus": "eliminated",
      "comment": null,
      "horse_name": "test horse",
      "country": "Algeria",
      "life_number": "234234"
    },
    {
      "participantId": 11,
      "rankStatus": null,
      "rank": null,
      "comment": null,
      "horse_name": "tesdfs",
      "country": "Afghanistan",
      "life_number": null
    },
    {
      "participantId": 10,
      "rankStatus": null,
      "comment": null,
      "horse_name": "nam horse",
      "country": "India",
      "life_number": "fh345"
    }
  ];
```

In above array of objects, I need to add `rank=0` to the objects where `rank` is not present.

I tried like below, but not able to figure it out correct way of doing this.

```
checklist.filter(x =>  !x.hasOwnProperty('rank') ).map(x => x.rank == 0);
```

What is right way of doing this? Please help and guide. Thanks

Comment: `x.rank == 0` returns a Boolean (true or false). You are replacing every item in your array with true or false, getting an array of `[ true, true, false, true]`. So no, it's probably not the right way :)

Comment: Also, just stating "it's not working" [is not sufficient](https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/)

Comment: @JeremyThille thanks for your comment. I will definitely improve with stack overflow guidance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would just do:

```
checklist.map(item => ({ rank: 0, ...item }))
```

Since you spread `item` after rank, if it has a `rank` the `0` will be overwritten, if it doesn't exist, it will end up with `0` for the rank.

If performance is a concern, it is probably more efficient to do:

```
checklist.forEach((item) => item.rank = item.rank || 0);
```